# Laravel Storage : 403 Access denied

Tags: laravel, symlink

Im using laravel 8. I'm having access denied to Storage.

The public folder is location in www/projectfolder and laravel files are in www/projectfolder/framework

I created a symbolic link

```
App::make('files')->link(storage_path('app/public'), public_path('../../storage'));
```

The upload is working fine I can find the uploaded files in `framework/storage/app/public` using FTP
the `{{asset('myfile.jpg')}}` gives the link `www.website.com/projectfodler/storage/myfile.jpg` but this link is giving :
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.

I cannot run any command as i'm on shared hosting with very limited control panel
any suggestion

Comment: your application should be outside of the public folder

Comment: run this command `php artisan storage:link` then try upload and read the file

Comment: You probably didn't set folder permissions.
 ​        ​run​: ​chmod -R 755 storage bootstrap/cache

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue doing the following :

1. `config\filesystems.php`

from

```
  'links' => [
      public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),  
    ],
```

to

```
  'links' => [
      '/home/USER/www/PROJECTFOLDER/storage' => storage_path('app/public'),
    ],
```

2. `app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php`

```
  public function register()
     {
         $this->app->bind('path.public', function() {
            return realpath('/home/USER/www/PROJECTFOLDER/storage');
         });
     }
```

3. `routes\web.php`

```
Route::get('/symlink', function () {
    Artisan::call('storage:link --relative');
});
```

4. Open [www.website.com/projectfolder/symlink](http://www.website.com/projectfolder/symlink) then remove the above from web.php
   and all are fine now.

Thanks